# Possible to change color of specific SVG path on button click?

Tags: java, android, svg

I have a SVG country map with different paths of provinces. Is it possible to change the color of a specific path (specific province) on button click? Every province has a unique name and ID in the SVG file. If necessary I can change the SVG file. The point that I don't have any clue how to target the path programatically with Java.

The SVG looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="612.54211"
   height="723.61865">
  
  <path
     d="bla bla some code"
     title="A"
     id="province-1" />
<path
     d="bla bla some code"
     title="B"
     id="province-2" />
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the point is that I don't know how to target the path programmatically in Android Studio. I updated my post with the SVG.

Comment: Depends how you're drawing the SVG since Android works with vectorDrawables which aren't SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. For any path you can set the fill attribut for set a specific color. Something like :

```
<path
     fill="#ffffff"
     d="bla bla some code"
     title="B"
     id="province-2" />
</svg>
```

But i don't have a solution for make it with Java. In JS you can take elements with tag, name, id and other something like document.QuerySelectorAll('svg') or document.getElementById('yourId') etc....